# Find the minimum $P=\frac{(a+b)^2}{b^2+2c^2+1}+\frac{(b+c)^2}{c^2+2a^2+1}+\frac{(c+a)^2}{a^2+2b^2+1}.$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $a,b,c\ge 0: a^2+b^2+c^2=1.$ Find the minimum $$P=\frac{(a+b)^2}{b^2+2c^2+1}+\frac{(b+c)^2}{c^2+2a^2+1}+\frac{(c+a)^2}{a^2+2b^2+1}.$$Due to the cyclic form, we can not let $a=b$

I tried to let $a=b=c=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$ and prove $P\ge 2.$

When I apply Cauchy-Schwarz $$P\ge \frac{4(a+b+c)^2}{3+3(a^2+b^2+c^2)}=(a+b+c)^2,$$but $a+b+c\ge \sqrt{2}$ is already wrong.

May be there is a better approach. Hope you help me find it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Proof.**

Setting $a=b=0;c=1$ we'll prove $P\ge \dfrac{3}{2},$

or $$\frac{(a+b)^2}{a^2+2b^2+3c^2}+\frac{(b+c)^2}{b^2+2c^2+3a^2}+\frac{(c+a)^2}{c^2+2a^2+3b^2}\ge \frac{3}{2}.$$
By using Holder inequality, \begin{align*}
    \sum_{cyc}\frac{(a+b)^2}{a^2+2b^2+3c^2}.\sum_{cyc}(2a+b)^2(a^2+2b^2+3c^2)\ge 9(a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+bc+ca)^2.\tag{1}
\end{align*}
Notice that $$\sum_{cyc}(2a+b)^2(a^2+2b^2+3c^2)=6\sum_{cyc}a^4+4\sum_{cyc}a^3b+8\sum_{cyc}ab^3+24\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2+12\sum_{cyc}a^2bc$$
$$\le 6\sum_{cyc}a^4+8\sum_{cyc}ab(a^2+b^2)+24\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2+12\sum_{cyc}a^2bc.\tag{2}$$
From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we need to prove $$3\left(\sum_{cyc}a^2+\sum_{cyc}bc\right)^2\ge 3\sum_{cyc}a^4+4\sum_{cyc}ab(a^2+b^2)+12\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2+6\sum_{cyc}a^2bc,$$which is equivalent to $$2\sum_{cyc}ab(a^2+b^2)-3\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2+6\sum_{cyc}a^2bc\ge 0,$$or $$2\sum_{cyc}ab(a-b)^2+\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2+6\sum_{cyc}a^2bc\ge 0.$$
The last inequality is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

For $b=c=0$ we obtain a value $\frac{3}{2}.$

We'll prove that it's a minimal value.

Indeed, we need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a+b)^2}{a^2+2b^2+3c^2}\geq\frac{3}{2}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(24a^5b+12a^5c-17a^4b^2-29a^4c^2+44a^3b^3+$$
$$+abc\sum_{cyc}(8a^3+28a^2b+28a^2c-26abc)\geq0,$$ which is true because $$\sum_{cyc}((24a^5b+12a^5c-17a^4b^2-29a^4c^2+44a^3b^3)=$$
$$\sum_{cyc}ab(24a^4-17a^3b+44a^2b^2-29ab^3+12b^4)$$ and
$$24x^4-17x^3+44x^2-29x+12=$$
$$=(24x^4-17x^3+4x^2)+(40x^2-29x+12)>0.$$

Comment: May I ask how did you transfer the homogenization to an inequality of $x$ ?